# Delete file through curl with -x option

Tags: curl, ftp

Update: This works if I run it through my desktop, but it seems the Q command doesn't work with the squid proxy.  Does anyone know of a way around this?

### curl -v -u user:pswd -Q "DELE test_file.txt" ftp://ftp.com

I have tried various versions of this curl statement to delete a file from an ftp server, but it just keeps trying to download the file (instead of deleting it) or it errors out (example below).  From what I have read, it looks like this may not be possible because of the -x argument?  I am unable to connect to the FTP without it.  I am running these from a shell script.

This one downloads the file:

```
curl -x ${PROXY_HOST_PORT} -u ${FTP_USER_PSWD} ${FILE_PATH} -Q "DELE $FILE"
```

This one errors out:

```
curl -X DELETE -x ${PROXY_HOST_PORT} -u ${FTP_USER_PSWD} ${FILE_PATH}


<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="ftp://ftpserver/folder/file">ftp://ftpserver/folder/file</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Unsupported Request Method and Protocol</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>Squid does not support all request methods for all access protocols. For example, you can not POST a Gopher request.</p>
```

Comment: `s/DELETE/"DELE"/`?